# How do I sum up aggregate data from individual level dataset?

Tags: stata

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str10 householdID byte(childID HHmemberID)
"0940041260" 1 3
"0940041030" 1 .
"0940041030" 2 .
"0940041030" 3 3
"0940041030" 4 .
"0940041030" 5 .
"0940041110" 1 3
"0940041100" 2 3
"0940041100" 3 4
"0940041100" 4 .
"0940041080" 1 .
"0940041080" 2 .
"0940041080" 3 .
"0940041060" 1 3
"0940041140" 1 .
"0940041180" 1 .
"0940041010" 1 .
"0940041010" 2 .
"0940041040" 1 .
"0940041040" 2 .
"0940041190" 1 .
"0940041190" 2 .
"0940041220" 1 3
"0940041160" 1 3
"0940041170" 1 .
"0940041170" 2 .
end
```

I am trying to sum up a household size and how many children a household has, but I don't know how to do that in Stata. Is there a way to deal with this problem? The greatest number of childID and HHmemberID will represent the number but I don't know how to extract the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this info in your original data, you can use extended generate:

```
bysort householdID: egen N_members = max(HHmemberID)
bysort householdID: egen N_kids    = max(childID)
```

If you want a new dataset with only that data, you should collapse:

```
collapse (max)  N_members = HHmemberID  N_kids = childID, by(householdID)
```